# Can't get a full length of binary data from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

**Table**

- id - int
- file - varbinary(max)

**Query**

```
SELECT file 
FROM Table 
WHERE id = 1
```

**Data**

The id `1` data has a file. And it's binary length is 836,412. But when I run the query, I only see a 43,680 bytes of binary data.

I tried to download the data as a CSV through *"Save Result as..."* button in the pop up panel. But still, I couldn't get a full length of the binary data.

In the CSV, there's only 16 bit (unsigned, 65534 length) data available. Unfortunately, I cannot request the data from my application at this moment. I have to pull it out from SSMS and convert it manually in my test code to see the file.

How can I get the full binary data from SSMS? Is there an option for displaying full length of binary data?

Comment: Add to the sql   ,  Len(file) as FLen .  This will verify that the full length is present on the table.  What was used to create that row in the table?  How can I duplicate the problem?  To create such a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try casting the "file" field to XML using a query such as the following...

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), file, 1) AS XML)
FROM Table
WHERE id = 1
```

However, you'll need to confirm that your SSMS Query options are set appropriately:

```
Query | Query Options... | Results | Grid | XML Data: unlimited
```

This will provide your results in hex, like so:

```
0x47494638396150003200F70 ...
```

Comment: but varchar only support 8000 bytes in max

Comment: ah double checked the document, varchar(max) can support up to 2GB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16